# JavaFX: New SpinnerValueFactory results in StackOverflow

Tags: java, javafx-8, spinner

I have a foreach loop creating about 180 panes and initalizing them. One part of the panes is a spinner. For each spinner a new SpinnerValueFactory is made:

```
SpinnerValueFactory factory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, products.get(i).getStock());
//getStock() returns an integer between 0 and 300
```

Every 6th time the foreach loop is gone through, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError (the following lines repeat)
    at javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory$IntegerSpinnerValueFactory.lambda$new$215(SpinnerValueFactory.java:475)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.setValue(SpinnerValueFactory.java:150)
at javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory$IntegerSpinnerValueFactory.lambda$new$215(SpinnerValueFactory.java:478)(...)
```

It looks like Java stops creating new SpinnerValueFactories due to a StackOverflow. Then Java tries to set the factory to the spinners, but as no factory exists, more errors are printed.
If I remove the method call, no error occurs:

```
SpinnerValueFactory factory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 5);
```

The project is nested in a database, a FXML file, its controller and a launching class. I tried to make a minimal example, but removing everything except the shortened method resulted in no error. Interestingly a friend of mine using the same project and the same SDK experiences no error. For me it also seems strange that it takes exactly 6 times to go through the foreach loop until the StackOverflow occurs whereas the second version creates all 180 panes without any problem. Why does the StackOverflow only occur when having the getStock() call?

Comment: Where is the factory created? Some context is needed for the code. It appears as if whenever a change occurs a new factory is created - is the line quoted inside a change listener, or called by one?

Comment: The factory is created in a method called updatePanes(). It is called when initializing the view for the first time and whenever a button in the view is clicked.
I receive the error when the method updatePanes() is called for the first time by initialize().

Comment: can you add a breakpoint at line SpinnerValueFactory factory = new ... and show us the stack trace (in your ide, eclipse, netbeans ...)

Comment: Is it possible that `getStock()` returns a negative value?

Comment: You're absoloutely right sillyfly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Debugger of my IDE (actually the first time) and found the option to set 'Java Exception Breakpoints'. It added some information to my exception:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGc7J.png

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate java.lang.Integer.toString()
value=-2
```

Obviously I set the factory's min value to 0 and tried to set the max value to -2 which doesn't work. I changed the value in the database and now it works fine. What an embarrassing fault. Thanks for your help!